# Scraping a specific group of <li> nested in <ul>

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to fetch a specific group of li nested in ul. Below is my starting code. The data I am trying to fetch is at https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Risikogebiete_neu.html. I highlighted the block of li(s) that I wanted to fetch.

```
> import requests from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
> # print(soup.prettify()) 
> page = requests.get('https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Risikogebiete_neu.html').text
> 
> soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser') 
> uls = soup.find_all('ul',id=None) 
> mine=[] 
> for ul in uls:
>     newsoup = BeautifulSoup(str(ul), 'html.parser')
>     lis = newsoup.find_all('li',id=None)
>     for li in lis:
>         mine.append(li.text)
>         print(li.text)
```

[image]

Comment: What's the special pattern that defines the logic for choosing this particular list (for example, "I want the first `ul` following a `p` with text starting with `"Gebiete"`...), or is it a one-off grab and you don't care how you get it? Also, you don't need to make new beautiful soup instances, the markup is already parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
token = 'Gebiete, die zu einem beliebigen Zeitpunkt in den vergangenen 14 Tagen Risikogebiete waren, aber derzeit KEINE mehr sind:'

no_longer_at_risk = soup.find_all(text=token)[0].findNext('ul').find_all('li')
```

This requires that the text we’re searching for doesn’t change — even just slightly! You could make it more robust by searching for a regular expression instead.

```
import re

token = re.compile(r'vergangen.*Risikogebiet.*keine.*mehr', re.I)
no_longer_at_risk = soup.find_all(text=token)[-1].findNext('ul').find_all('li')
```

But fundamentally the best way would probably be to iterate over all nodes in the document and check which matches the most of a list of tokens (e.g. `['Gebiet', 'Risikogebiet', 'vergangen', 'kein', 'mehr']`).

Comment: I am not sure if the text ever changes; I wish rki had used a table instead. Also, I made a mistake in my initial post as I plan to capture all countries except for the no longer at risk.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with the Xpath. This allows you to select a specific element in the document by specifying the entire nesting from the top level. Note that this is very brittle because it will break if any nesting changes.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this depending on your use case and expectations for the structure; if it's a one-time scrape or you anticipate text or markup will change.

One option is to pick the element that immediately precedes the `sectionRelated` class:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> page = requests.get("https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Risikogebiete_neu.html").text
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
>>> lis = soup.select_one(".sectionRelated").previous_sibling.previous_sibling.select("li")
>>> [x.text[:20] for x in lis]
['Rumänien: Gebiete („', 'Belgien: Provinz Ant', 'Bulgarien: Oblast Do']
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that I ended up using to accomplish my tasker. I am sure it can further improved.

> ```
> import requests, re
> import pandas as pd
> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
> # print(soup.prettify())
> #print("Loading...")
> page = requests.get('https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Risikogebiete_neu.html').text
> soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
> countries=[]
> result = re.compile(r'Ebenso wird berücksichtigt, wenn keine verlässlichen Informationen für bestimmte Staaten vorliegen.',re.I)
> lis=soup.find_all(text=result)[-1].findNext('ul').find_all('li')
> for value in lis:
>     if re.match(r"^<ul><li>.+",str(value)):
>         pass
>     elif re.match(r"^<li><p>.+",str(value)):
>         pass
>     else:
>         countries.append(re.findall(r"(?<=\>)(.*?)(?=\()",str(value)))
>    
> flattened  = [val for sublist in countries for val in sublist]
> df =pd.DataFrame(flattened, columns=['No_Go_Country'])
> df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Anodaram\Desktop\no_go_countries.xlsx',sheet_name='No_Go_Countries',index=None)
> ```